# How can i set Bottomnavigation item checked on backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Dears,

I have a bottomnavigation menu and each menu has a one fragment. I added addToBackStack for each fragment and its working good when click back button except menu item check state. Sorry i just started learning android programming and its hard to explain situation for me. So let me demonstrate.

[image]

As you see above image when i click "Application" menu item everything is perfect. But after that if i click back button its redirecting to "Featured" fragment and i able to see "Featured" fragment view(as i expected) but Featured button is not checked. It seems like its still on "Application". So how can i set "Featured" item to active/checked after i click back button.

Comment: Have you checked this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886228/7954210 ?

Comment: No im checking now. I hope it will work.

Comment: Glad to hear that